# Bipartition of a Lattice Graph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to show the bipartite-ness of a 3D Lattice Graph, which is a
graph of nodes $(i,j,k) \in \mathbb{N}^3$ where there is an edge
between $(i_1,j_1,k_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2,k_2)$ if and only if
$|i_1 - i_2| = 1 \vee |j_1 - j_2| = 1 \vee |k_1 - k_2| = 1.$ I did something
similar to this with a 2D lattice, but I'm having issues generalizing this into
a 3D form. perhaps I could consider partitioning on the quality of the sum
$i+j+k$?

Comment: Perhaps you mean the *parity* of the sum $i+j+k$, not the *quality*.  Also, in your condition, I believe that you want the exclusive or, not the inclusive or.  Yes, the parity of $i+j+k$ partitions this lattice because if two vertices are connected, exactly one of their coordinates differs by $1$, so the difference is $|(i_1+j_1+k_1)-(i_2+j_2+k_2)|=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph is not bipartite, it contains the triangle $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(3,1,0)$